# Navigation controller between two UITableViewControllers in Swift

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode

I am looking for a way to insert a navigation controller between two UITableViewControllers. I have a UITabBarController which then connects to a UITable which then connects to another UITable. I have attached a picture below to give a better reference at what I am talking about.

[image: Main Storyboard]

So from UITabBar, you go to the first table, from that, you make a selection and go to another table. The second table is where I want my back button. I know in the screenshot you can see the back button present but for some reason it does not show it at run time. 
Moreover, when I try to embed Navigation Controller in the first table, I get an error in the code below.

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let barViewControllers = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
        let destinationViewController = barViewControllers.viewControllers?[0] as! MainVC
        destinationViewController.TPNumber = txtTpNumber.text!
        destinationViewController.intake = intake

        let DVC = barViewControllers.viewControllers?[1] as! AttendanceTVC //This is where I get an error
        DVC.TPNumber = txtTpNumber.text!

    }
```

If anyone could guide me on how I can solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your storyboard and click your Attendance (ViewController), than click your menu "Editor" -> "Embed in" -> UINavigationController.

Comment: I did that, but see my question again. The code I have attached, I get an error there. Since I am sending a variable from my login page to Attendance view controller, that seems to have a problem. "Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x211cb4280) to 'Attendance_APU.AttendanceTVC' (0x104f9ad50)." This is what it says.

Comment: Thank you so much, just needed to modify a code a bit, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can firstly cast this destination as UINavigationController and then you can access the controller embed in UINavigationController by it's topViewController property